# How to find what variables event listeners send to the functions they call?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm having trouble understanding event listeners and what variables they send to the function they call.

For example, I added an event listener to this cell with the intention of calling a function which checks if the mouse is pressed down while moving over an element:

```
cell.addEventListener("mousemove", cellControl);
```

```
function cellControl(e) {
    if (e.buttons == 1) {
        // Do things
    }
}
```

I was able to make this function work by finding other stack overflow answers but I don't understand why it works. The event listener calls `cellControl` without passing any variables, but the function `cellControl` receives an object anyways which I can check for data.

Why did the event listener send this data, and how can I find out what data different event listeners send to the functions I call? I read through [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp) but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: A callback is a function you pass to another function as an argument. In your case you are passing the function cellControl to the addEventListener function. You have to know (from the documentation) that addEventListener will invoke the callback function with one argument which is the event object.

Comment: "*The event listener calls `cellControl` without passing any variables*" - no, there's no call of `cellControl()` in `cell.addEventListener("mousemove", cellControl);`. `cellControl` *is* the event listener, and the event listener will be called with an event object as the argument, later, when that event occurs.

Comment: w3schools is useless as usual. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event instead.

Comment: @Bergi got it, I figured I was using a bad or incomplete source for learning about events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the callback accepts a single parameter: an object based on Event describing the event that has occurred

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback

The parameter is a JavaScript Event Object. You can find the properties here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#properties

Answer (score 1):

The callback function you supply to the addEventListener function can be an anonymous function. It would look like this:

```
cell.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    cellControl(e);
});
```

That can be useful if you want to supply other arguments to the callback function in addition to the event object:

```
cell.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    cellControl(e, anotherArgument);
});
```

You can find more about the event object as mentioned in the answer from Michael. I also find it very useful to console.log the event object or just certain properties of it. For example:

```
function cellControl(e) {
    console.log('e', e);
    console.log('e.buttons', e.buttons);
    if (e.buttons == 1) {
        // Do things
    }
}
```

Now if you look at the console tab in your browser's developer tools (Ctrl Shift K in Firefox) you will see the information about the event object you want so long as you mouseover the relevant element in your web page.

To address your question,

> how can I find out what data different event listeners send to the functions I call?

The addEventListener() method (ie. function) will always send the event object to the callback and nothing else. The event object will be different for almost every case but the properties will be (largely or possibly totally???) the same. The values of the properties will be different of course.